# Storyboard, Segues. What should I do if I want to use two segues from one element?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, tableview, segue

This is my first question here. I have TableViewController and I want to use two segues from one raw. One segue should work when you tapped a row, and the second is action from this row. Every of them need to show different ViewControllers and I don't understand how can I do that because I can't to create two segues from one row. The problem is that both of cases need to call prepare function and it called only with segue, and it does not called when I use performSegue.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Add"){(_,_, completionHandler) in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editQuiz", sender: self)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete"){(_,_, completionHandler) in
            CoreDataManager.shared.deleteSomeQuizData(data: CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes[indexPath.row], indexNumber: indexPath.row)
            self.navigationItem.title = "\(CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes.count) quizzes"
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {return}
        print(segue.source)
        if segue.identifier == "editQuiz" {
            guard let destination = segue.destination as? AddWordsViewController else{return}
        }
        if segue.identifier == "showQuiz" {
            guard let destination = segue.destination as? QuizViewController else{return}
            destination.from = Int(CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes[indexPath.row].from)
            destination.to = Int(CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes[indexPath.row].to)
        }
    }
```

prepare(for segue:) works only when it called from row segue to another ViewController and it didn't called with performSegue. Also if I create both of segue from TableViewController to ViewControllers and don't call performSegue, transition doesn't work.

All of the segues identifiers set correctly.

Even if I try

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showQuiz", sender: self)
    }
```

prepare(for segue:) is calling, but in

```
let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Add"){(_,_, completionHandler) in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editQuiz", sender: self)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

it does not calling.

Comment: To give yourself the most control, don't use segues in that situation... Instantiate the view controller you want to display, and then either present it or push it as needed.

Comment: @DonMag To be honest I am just learning. I was learning by official apple's books and they didn't tell me how to do it. Can I use something like prepare(for segue:) in that case?

Comment: The easiest way to have 2 segue on the same row is to add one for the row and one for the accessory. I think you could also add a segue to a button you add in the cell.

Comment: @PtitXav I created the second for TableViewController and used performSegue, but unfortunately, it did not call prepare method.I don't know how to add a segue to an action in a row because I create this action only programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have almost everything setup correctly, except...

In your `prepare for segue` code, the first thing you do is check for the selected row:

```
guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {return}
```

If you call `performSegue` from your "Edit" action, the table view will NOT HAVE a selected row.

A bit tough for me to test because I don't have all of your data management and destination controllers, but this should fix the issue (if you have your segues setup correctly in Storyboard):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Add"){(_,_, completionHandler) in
        
        // instead of passing self as sender
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editQuiz", sender: self)
        
        // pass the indexPath
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editQuiz", sender: indexPath)
        
        // no need to reload data here
        //tableView.reloadData()
    }
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete"){(_,_, completionHandler) in
        CoreDataManager.shared.deleteSomeQuizData(data: CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes[indexPath.row], indexNumber: indexPath.row)
        self.navigationItem.title = "Title \(indexPath.row)" // "\(CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes.count) quizzes"
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "editQuiz" {
        // do something before segue to AddWordsViewController
        if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
            print("editQuiz with IndexPath: \(indexPath)")
        }
    }
    if segue.identifier == "showQuiz" {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
              let destination = segue.destination as? QuizViewController
        else {
            // note: this will NOT Stop the segue
            return
        }
        destination.from = Int(CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes[indexPath.row].from)
        destination.to = Int(CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes[indexPath.row].to)
    }
    
}
```

---

As I mentioned in my comment: *"To give yourself the most control, don't use segues in that situation..."*

To do that, **delete the segues** from your Storyboard.

Instead, use code like this to instantiate the "destination" view controllers as needed:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    // instantiate QuizViewController
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuizViewController") as? QuizViewController {

        vc.from = Int(CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes[indexPath.row].from)
        vc.to = Int(CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes[indexPath.row].to)
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Add"){(_,_, completionHandler) in
        
        // instantiate AddWordsViewController
        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddWordsViewController") as? AddWordsViewController {

            // do something before showing AddWordsViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

        }
        
    }
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete"){(_,_, completionHandler) in
        CoreDataManager.shared.deleteSomeQuizData(data: CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes[indexPath.row], indexNumber: indexPath.row)
        self.navigationItem.title = "Title \(indexPath.row)" // "\(CoreDataManager.shared.quizzes.count) quizzes"
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])
}
```